# Winsock2.h can't send http requests

Tags: c++, http, networking, winsock2

Salutations fellow programmers,

I am trying to write a program that allows you input what you want and the program will send your input to the server.

At the moment, my goal is sending HTTP requests to a web page. It connects fine. But when the while loop runs in immediately sends something through the cin.getline procedure without me inputting anything. I thought this was weird but it seemed to be work anyway.

Every time I send something like: "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n" it will return the correct thing, but anything else I input, like "OPTIONS" returns the source code + "application blocked" (I am at school so it makes sense).

So, I connected to hotspot shield VPN and tested the application, but to my horror when I input something to send it returns nothing.

I searched through stack overflow and google but I haven't been able to find anything so far; probably because I'm searching for the wrong solutions to the problem. 
Anyway, if you have time, please scan through the code send some help. It could just be a VPN and school issue and I could try at home if the code seems to be working for you, so just let me know.

SPECIFIC OUTLINE OF PROBLEM:
When I use this outside the school network nothing is returned and the while loop doesn't seem to execute. I can connect but the program seems to be in an endless time-out or something.

```
    cout << "Connected to " << hostName << endl;



    while (true) {
        cout << ">";


        cin.getline(sendBuf, sizeof(sendBuf));
        string s(sendBuf);


        cout << s.c_str() << endl;


            send(connectSocket, s.c_str(), sizeof(s.c_str()), 0);

            int rec = recv(connectSocket, recvBuf, sizeof(recvBuf), 0);
            if (rec > 0) {
                cout << recvBuf << endl;
            }
            else if (rec <= 0) {
                cout << "nothing" << endl;
            }
        }

    system("pause");

}
system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my goal is sending HTTP requests to a web page

The code you showed does not attempt to implement any semblance of the [HTTP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), not even close.

For one thing, if you look at your own example more carefully, you will see that the `GET` request (which BTW, is missing a required `Host` header, due to your use of HTTP 1.1) contains 2 line breaks, but `cin.getline()` (why not `std::getline()`?) reads only 1 line at a time.  So, you read in one line, send it, and wait for a response that doesn't arrive since you didn't finish sending a complete request yet.  That would explain why your `while` loop is hanging.

If you want the user to type in a complete HTTP request and then you send it as-is, you have to read in the ENTIRE request from the user, and then send it entirely to the server, before you can then attempt to receive the server's response.  That means you have to handle line breaks between individual message headers, handle the terminating line break that separates the message headers from the message body, and detect the end of the body data.

I would suggest not relying on the user typing in a complete HTTP request as-is.  I suggest you prompt the user for relevant pieces and let the user type normal text, and then your code can format that text into a proper HTTP request as needed.

When you are reading the server's response, you can't just blindly read arbitrary chunks of data.  You have to process what you read, per the rules of the HTTP protocol.  This is particularly important in order to determine when you have reached the end of the response and need to stop reading.  The end of the response can be signaled in one of many different ways, as outlined in [RFC 2616 Section 4.4 Message Length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4).

You are also making some common newbie mistakes in your TCP handling in general.  TCP is a streaming transport, you are not taking into account that `send()` and `recv()` can sent/receive fewer bytes than requested.  Or that `recv()` does not return null-terminated data.

With that said, try something like this:

```
void sendAll(SOCKET sckt, const void *buf, int buflen)
{
    // send all bytes until buflen has been sent,
    // or an error occurs...

    const char *pbuf = static_cast<const char*>(buf);

    while (buflen > 0)
    {
        int numSent = send(sckt, pbuf, buflen, 0);
        if (numSent < 0) {
            std::ostringstream errMsg;
            errMsg << "Error sending to socket: " << WSAGetLastError();
            throw std::runtime_error(errMsg.str());
        }
        pbuf += numSent;
        buflen -= numSent;
    }
}

int readSome(SOCKET sckt, void *buf, int buflen)
{
    // read as many bytes as possible until buflen has been received,
    // the socket is disconnected, or an error occurs...

    char *pbuf = static_cast<char*>(buf);
    int total = 0;

    while (buflen > 0)
    {
        int numRecvd = recv(sckt, pbuf, buflen, 0);
        if (numRecvd < 0) {
            std::ostringstream errMsg;
            errMsg << "Error receiving from socket: " << WSAGetLastError();
            throw std::runtime_error(errMsg.str());
        }
        if (numRecvd == 0) break;
        pbuf += numRecvd;
        buflen -= numRecvd;
        total += numRecvd;
    }

    return total;
}

void readAll(SOCKET sckt, void *buf, int buflen)
{
    // read all bytes until buflen has been received,
    // or an error occurs...

    if (readSome(sckt, buf, buflen) != buflen)
        throw std::runtime_error("Socket disconnected unexpectedly");
}

std::string readLine(SOCKET sckt)
{
    // read a line of characters until a line break is received...

    std::string line;
    char c;

    do
    {
        readAll(sckt, &c, 1);
        if (c == '\r')
        {
            readAll(sckt, &c, 1);
            if (c == '\n') break;
            line.push_back('\r');
        }
        else if (c == '\n') {
            break;
        }
        line.push_back(c);
    }
    while (true);

    return line;
}

...

inline void ltrim(std::string &s) {
    // erase whitespace on the left side...
    s.erase(s.begin(), std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](int ch) {
        return !std::isspace(ch);
    }));
}

inline void rtrim(std::string &s) {
    // erase whitespace on the right side...
    s.erase(std::find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), [](int ch) {
        return !std::isspace(ch);
    }).base(), s.end());
}

inline void trim(std::string &s) {
    // erase whitespace on both sides...
    ltrim(s);
    rtrim(s);
}

inline void upperCase(std::string &s)
{
    // translate all characters to upper-case...
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::toupper);
}

...

std::string makeRequest(const std::string &host, const std::string &method, const std::string &resource, const std::vector<std::string> &extraHeaders, const void *body, int bodyLength)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << method << " " << resource << " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    oss << "Host: " << host << "\r\n";
    oss << "Content-Length: " << bodyLength << "\r\n";
    for(auto &hdr : extraHeaders)
    {
        // TODO: ignore Host and Content-Length...
        oss << hdr << "\r\n";
    }
    oss << "\r\n";
    oss.write(static_cast<const char*>(body), bodyLength);
    return oss.str();
}

bool getHeaderValue(const std::vector<std::string> &headers, const std::string &headerName, std::string &value)
{
    value.clear();

    std::string toFind = headerName;
    upperCase(toFind);

    // find the requested header by name...
    for(auto &s : headers)
    {
        std::string::size_type pos = s.find(':');
        if (pos != std::string::npos)
        {
            std::string name = s.substr(0, pos-1);
            trim(name);
            upperCase(name);
            if (name == toFind)
            {
                // now return its value...
                value = s.substr(pos+1);
                trim(value);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // name not found
    return false;
}

...

std::cout << "Connected to " << hostName << std::endl;

try
{
    std::string method, resource, hdr, data;
    std::string status, version, reason;
    std::vector<std::string> headers;
    int statusCode, rec;

    do
    {
        headers.clear();
        data.clear();

        // get user input
    
        std::cout << "Method > " << std::flush;
        if (!std::getline(std::cin, method))
            throw std::runtime_error("Error reading from stdin");
        upperCase(method);

        std::cout << "Resource > " << std::flush;
        if (!std::getline(std::cin, resource))
            throw std::runtime_error("Error reading from stdin");

        std::cout << "Extra Headers > " << std::flush;
        while (std::getline(std::cin, hdr) && !hdr.empty())
            headers.push_back(hdr);
        if (!std::cin)
            throw std::runtime_error("Error reading from stdin");

        std::cout << "Data > " << std::flush;
        // use Ctrl-Z or Ctrl-D to end the data, depending on platform...
        std::ios_base::fmtflags flags = std::cin.flags();
        std::cin >> std::noskipws;
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<char>(), std::back_inserter(data));
        if (!std::cin)
            throw std::runtime_error("Error reading from stdin");
        std::cin.flags(flags);
        std::cin.clear();

        // send request

        std::string request = makeRequest(hostName, method, resource, headers, data.c_str(), data.length());
        std::cout << "Sending request: << std::endl << request << std::endl;

        // TODO: reconnect to hostName if previous request disconnected...
        sendAll(connectSocket, request.c_str(), request.length());

        // receive response
    
        headers.clear();
        data.clear();

        // read the status line and parse it...
        status = readLine(connectSocket);
        std::cout << status << std::endl;    
        std::getline(std::istringstream(status) >> version >> statusCode, reason);
        upperCase(version);

        // read the headers...
        do
        {
            hdr = readLine(connectSocket);
            std::cout << hdr << std::endl;
            if (hdr.empty()) break;
            headers.push_back(hdr);
        }
        while (true);

        // The transfer-length of a message is the length of the message-body as
        // it appears in the message; that is, after any transfer-codings have
        // been applied. When a message-body is included with a message, the
        // transfer-length of that body is determined by one of the following
        // (in order of precedence):

        // 1. Any response message which "MUST NOT" include a message-body (such
        // as the 1xx, 204, and 304 responses and any response to a HEAD
        // request) is always terminated by the first empty line after the
        // header fields, regardless of the entity-header fields present in
        // the message.
        if (((statusCode / 100) != 1) &&
            (statusCode != 204) &&
            (statusCode != 304) &&
            (method != "HEAD"))
        {
            // 2. If a Transfer-Encoding header field (section 14.41) is present and
            // has any value other than "identity", then the transfer-length is
            // defined by use of the "chunked" transfer-coding (section 3.6),
            // unless the message is terminated by closing the connection.
            if (getHeaderValue(headers, "Transfer-Encoding", hdr))
                upperCase(hdr);
            if (!hdr.empty() && (hdr != "IDENTITY"))
            {
                std::string chunk;
                std::string::size_type oldSize, size;

                do
                {
                    chunk = readLine(connectSocket);

                    std::istringstream(chunk) >> std::hex >> size;
                    if (size == 0) break;

                    oldSize = data.size();
                    chunkData.resize(oldSize + size);
                    readAll(connectSocket, &data[oldSize], size);
                    std::cout.write(&data[oldSize], size);

                    readLine(connectSocket);
                }
                while (true);

                std::cout << std::endl;

                do
                {
                    hdr = readLine(connectSocket);
                    std::cout << hdr << std::endl;
                    if (hdr.empty()) break;
                    headers.push_back(hdr);
                }
                while (true);
            }

            // 3. If a Content-Length header field (section 14.13) is present, its
            // decimal value in OCTETs represents both the entity-length and the
            // transfer-length. The Content-Length header field MUST NOT be sent
            // if these two lengths are different (i.e., if a Transfer-Encoding
            // header field is present). If a message is received with both a
            // Transfer-Encoding header field and a Content-Length header field,
            // the latter MUST be ignored.
            else if (getHeaderValue(headers, "Content-Length", hdr))
            {
                std::string::size_type size;
                if ((std::istringstream(hdr) >> size) && (size > 0))
                {
                    data.resize(size);
                    readAll(connectSock, &data[0], size);
                    std::cout << data;
                }
            }

            // 4. If the message uses the media type "multipart/byteranges", and the
            // transfer-length is not otherwise specified, then this self-
            // delimiting media type defines the transfer-length. This media type
            // MUST NOT be used unless the sender knows that the recipient can parse
            // it; the presence in a request of a Range header with multiple byte-
            // range specifiers from a 1.1 client implies that the client can parse
            // multipart/byteranges responses.
            else if (getHeaderValue(headers, "Content-Type", hdr) &&
                    (hdr.compare(0, 10, "multipart/") == 0))
            {
                // TODO: extract 'boundary' attribute and read from
                // socket until the terminating boundary is reached...
            }

            // 5. By the server closing the connection.
            else
            {
                do
                {
                    rec = readSome(connectSocket, recvBuf, sizeof(recvBuf));
                    if (rec == 0) break;
                    data.append(recvBuf, rec);
                    std::cout.write(recvBuf, rec);
                }
                while (rec == sizeof(recvBuf));
            }
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;

        // use status, headers, and data as needed ...

        getHeaderValue(headers, "Connection", hdr);
        upperCase(hdr);

        if (version == "HTTP/1.0")
        {
            if (hdr != "KEEP-ALIVE")
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (hdr == "CLOSE")
                break;
        }
    }
    while (true);
}
catch (const std::exception &e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}

closesocket(connectSocket);
std::cout << "Disconnected from " << hostName << std::endl;

std::system("pause");
```

Isn't HTTP fun? :-)  This is, by far, not a complete HTTP implementation, but it should get you started.  However, as you can see, HTTP can be quite complex to implement from scratch, and it has many rules and restrictions that you have to follow.  You are better off not implementing HTTP manually at all. There are plenty of 3rd party HTTP libraries that are available for C++.  Use one of them instead, and let them handle the hard work for you, so you can focus on your own business logic.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. I understand what you have told me and also get the sense that I am diving into the deep-ish end of c++ too quickly, so I'll have to hit Bjarne Strousoup's bible on c++ again... ;(.
and yeah HTTP is fun, but I think I'm too novice to be doing this after reading your code, I'll have a look through the std library as well and get a better grasp of it. Thank you,